# Delete out defined characters, in a random position in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to address each cell in a column and delete out certain
substrings, but keep the remaining substrings. the wanted and unwanted 
substrings could be in any order.

The format of the substrings to delete is as follows:

```
OS##
OS#
OS##.#
OS##.##
OS#.#
OS#.##
##OS
#OS
##.#OS
##.##OS
#.#OS
#.##OS
#+##
##+##
###+##
####+##
#####+##
######+##
```

Here is some sample data:

```
38OS 
15OS 1+00
15OS 10+00 15OS "text to keep"
"text to keep" 15OS 
"text to keep" 23OS "text to keep" 1+00
```

Comment: You should be able to find and replace the text to remove easily enough. If those are patterns, VBA does support regular expressions What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using SPLIT function, INSTR with no luck. LEFT, RIGHT, and MID won't work because I don't know where the string to be removed will fall.

Comment: You are going to want to use regex to capture the patterns you mentioned above. Either way, this is going to be a taxing project given the amount of patterns to be identified

Comment: find and replace doesn't seem to work because if there is a ##+## , it will remove #+## and leave a single # left over

Comment: how about something where you tell VBA - find a substring containing "OS" or "+", and delete that substring?

Comment: Regex should do it: `OS\d{1,2}(\.\{1,2})?`, `\{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?OS` and `\d{1,5}\+\{2,2}` are the three patterns you would need (NB: these are untested)

Comment: I'l' give that a go - thank you!

Comment: @user11173377 That would delete substrings that should not be deleted. eg. `BOSS`, `a+b=c`

Comment: @user11173377 I first tried Regex and a very simple pattern `"^OS+"` removes leading `OS` sub-string. I have a limited exposure to Regex patterns. However I could remove `OS` sub-strings by using a formula `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"OS","")," (",", OS (")` and on results in second step removed `.` by another formula `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(E1,".","")," (",", . (")`. Sample results as per your data <https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzfr8muxc1xsnp0/55071941-delete-out-defined-characters.xlsx?dl=0> Please look into it , if it is any way useful to you.

Comment: Thank you @skkakkar One thing I should clarify here - I want to delete the characters "OS", as well as the adjacent numbers in the substring. There may be other comments or "codes" in the string that I'd like to keep. In the first list above, the entire strings would be deleted out. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: @user11173377 your comment seems to be incomplete. Please elaborate further.

Comment: It should be complete now - I'm referring to the first list in my original post